# Angular Material mat-table multiple header dynamic use

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to add a dropdown menu in the first row under the header. I create a dynamic table so the column are not fixed and the dropdown Menu should be in every column. However i get so many error that I dont know how to achieve it. Maybe ngFor at container "item-description" or add the html in the array, but I don't know how to set it correctly. Here is my table.

```html
     <table mat-table [dataSource]="viewSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let column of viewData" matColumnDef="{{column}}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{column}}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element[column]}}</td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="item-description">
        <th mat-header-cell> 
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Select Parent</mat-label>
            <mat-select>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let column of savedData" [value]="column">
                {{column}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field> 
        </th>
      </ng-container>
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="viewData"></tr>
      <tr mat-header-row [hidden]="dropData.length == 0" *matHeaderRowDef="['item-description']"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: viewData; let i = index"></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are getting is that the html component of the page are loadiing and the information is not there yet, so when the *ngFor is trying to generete te column is getting null in the viewData, what I wold recomend is that wait until the data is there with an *ngIf and after that create the column

Comment: The table will be loaded after the data is there, is it not the problem. i just want to add a dropdown row in the table. Idk if its possible to add HTML component into an array, this is why i asked to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic columns, use this

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="viewSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns">
        <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                {{ viewData[column] }}
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                {{ element[column] }}
            </td>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let headerColumn of headerColumns">
        <ng-container [matColumnDef]="headerColumn">
            <th mat-header-cell> 
                <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>Select Parent</mat-label>
                    <mat-select>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let column of savedData [value]="column">
                            {{column}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field> 
            </th>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></tr>
    <tr mat-header-row [hidden]="dropData.length == 0" *matHeaderRowDef="headerColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns></tr>
</table>
```

`columns` and `headerColumns` would respectively be a `string[]` representation of your dynamic columns and header columns.